# Find , $P(X \le 2)$, $P(X > 2)$ and $P(X=2)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

$$F(x)=  \cases{0 & if $x<0$\\
        \frac{x}{4} & if $ 0 \le x <2$\\
      1 & if $x \le 2$}$$

Find , $P(X \le 2)$, $P(X >  2)$ and $P(X=2)$

for $P(X \le 2)$ = $F(2)=1$
for $P(X > 2)$=$1-F(2)=0$
for $P(X=2)$=$F(2)- P(X =1)-P(X=0) $ =1- $\frac{1}{2} =\frac{1}{2} $

is this correct?

Comment: @rae306 $X$ is a continuous random variable if and only if its CDF is continuous. But that is not the case here. The defined $F$ is not continuous at $2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first two statements are okay.

It is not correct to state that $P(X=2)=F(2)-P(X=1)$.

What we do have is: $$P(X=2)=P(X\leq2)-P(X<2)$$ where $P(X\leq2)=F(2)$ and $P(X<2)=\lim_{x\uparrow2}F(x)=\frac24$ and resulting in: $$P(X=2)=1-\frac24=\frac12$$

Comment: thankyou for last part i need to take limit? $P(X=2)=1-\frac24=\frac12$ its the same as $F(2)-F(2)^{-1}$?

Comment: Yes, the limit coming from left. Personally I would write $F(2)-F_-(2)$.

Comment: thanks! isnt it also same with $F(2)- P(X =1)-P(X=0)$? since 0 elsewhere ?

Comment: No. Be aware that $P(X=1)=F(1)-F_-(1)=\frac14-\frac14=0$. You are not dealing with the distribution of a discrete random variable $X$ taking values only on $\{0,1,2\}$ as you seem to think.

Comment: how do you know if it is continuous or discrete? and how to know whether it will be 0 or not when P(x=a) is 0 for continuous?

Comment: If and only if $F$ is a continuous function then the corresponding distribution is continuous. In all cases we have $P(X=a)=F(a)-F_-(a)$ for every $a$ and continuity of $F$ then implies that $P(X=a)=0$ for every $a$. Also the opposite is true: if $P(X=a)=0$ for every $a$ then $X$ has continuous distribution.

Comment: thankyou so much! but in this question discontinuous at 2, but P is not zero? it is 0 if $f(x)=$ 0?

Comment: There is indeed a discontinuity at $2$ and consequently $P(X=2)>0$. It is unclear to me what you mean with $f(x)=0$. No $f(x)$ is mentioned in your question.